# Passing structure pointer to a function with index vs without

Tags: c++

Say I have the prototypes,

```
void display(const someStruct& ptr);
void display(const someStruct& ptr, int arraySize);
```

where ptr is of type

```
simeStruct *ptr = new someStruct[arraySize];
```

Say that the structure has a variety of members, obviously, and the ptr has already been used to populate. Now, if I want to display the first index, I'd call it as,

```
someNamespace::display(pKingdom[0]);
```

implementation being,

```
void display(const someStruct& ptr) {
    cout << ptr.someMember1 << ", " << ptr.someMember2;
}
```

Would I be able to call the whole structure here if I used the overloaded function by calling it as,

```
simeNamespace::display(ptr[arraySize], arraySize);
```

or is that call invalid? Upon compilation, is it trying to print from the first cell, or is it going to print garbage because the call is incorrect?

Edit: forgot the implementation of overload function

```
void display(const someStruct& ptr, int arraySize) {
    cout << "SomeOutput is" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << ptr.someMember1 << ", " << ptr.someMember2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile and run your code? Your question may be more appropriate on /codereview

Comment: `pKingdom[arraySize]` dereferences the array one past the last element (based on the way you are creating it)

Comment: Also `const someStruct& ptr` is confusing/misleading, as `ptr` is not a pointer, but a (`const`) reference

Comment: @Nielk Definitely not a good fit for codereview. Asking for an explanation of a piece of code is one of the explicit Off-Topic reasons.

Comment: It seems you are confusing pointers and references. `const someStruct& ptr` is not a pointer, it's a reference on a const object. You cannot use it to refere to an array.

Comment: @Actarus Interesting, so it should be `void display(const someStruct* ptr)` and `void display(const someStruct* ptr, int arraySize);`, and then just pass it as `display(&ptr[0]);` and `display(&ptr[arraySize], arraySize);`?

Comment: It's weird that you are writing a C++ program while using C constructs (passing a pointer along with the size information), when you could simply use `std::vector`. Also, functions accepting a reference as the first parameter are often candidates for member functions (which will be accessing the instance through the implicit `this` reference). It would perhaps make more sense to have `someStruct::toString()` and then do whatever you like with the string representation of the struct.

Comment: `ptr` is a pointer.    Your display functions expect a reference.   You cannot pass a pointer to a function expecting a reference.   And (unless a reference is to an array, which is not what `Display()` expects) you cannot use a reference as if it is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `void display(const Foo& ref, int arraySize)` function awaits object Foo passed, then takes it's reference, that means your method able to change original Foo directly (`const` gonna prevent this, but as @aschepler mentioned, it's still possible)

To access memory you allocated, you want to pass pointer, it's gonna be like:

```
void display(const Bar* ptr, int arraySize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        std::cout << i + 1 << ") " << ptr[i].a << ", " << ptr[i].b << "\n";
    }
}
```

Usage `display(barPtr, arraySize);` where `Bar *barPtr = new Bar[arraySize]`. Or, if you still wanna pass by reference do like this:

```
void display(const Bar (&ref)[100], int arraySize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        std::cout << i + 1 << ") " << ref[i].a << ", " << ref[i].b << "\n";
    }
}
```

In this case you need to write size (100 just for example, it can't be variable) in the declaration, and usage `display(bar, arraySize);`, where `Bar bar [arraySize]`. Of course you could use template for this:

```
template <unsigned int N>
void display(const Bar (&ref)[N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::cout << i + 1 << ") " << ref[i].a << ", " << ref[i].b << "\n";
    }
}
```

usage come to `display<arraySize>(bar);`, where `Bar bar [arraySize]` your actual object. But, in this case, I would suggest you to use containers, such `vector`.

Comment: No, you can't change the `Foo` directly, because the parameter is `const Foo&`, not `Foo&`.  This might be better than having a plain `Foo` parameter, which could require making a copy.  (You could use `const_cast`, but that would be sneaky and dangerous.)

Comment: @aschepler I meant it gives you ability to change it, of course `const` keyword gonna prevent this :)